# Is there any way to view the logs and save the content that is being printed (from the printer or my computer)

Tags: printing, printers, network-printers

I have a printer that is shared in the local network.

Is there any way to view the logs and save the content that is being printed from the printer? (by connecting a USB or hard disk drive) or from my computer?

'[PaperCut Print Logger](https://www.papercut.com/products/free-software/print-logger/)' only saves a few details about the paper and the person that prints it. I am searching for a way to save the content that is printed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This question could be better suited for other Stack Exchange communities rather than SO. You are also missing key information, like what OS you are using.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.